# jQuery: remove class added by ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It's not clear to me how i can remove a class that is added by an ajax success function. I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    [...]
    success:function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('[name="'+data[i]+'"]').addClass('tmvc_err');
        }
    },
});
```

It basically add a red border to those fields that doesn't pass my php validation script.
Now, i'm tryin to remove that red border (or better, tryin to remove class .tmvc_err) after change event. This is not working:

```
$(".tmvc_err").on('change', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tmvc_err');
});
```

It is in a document ready, so i guess the problem is that as the class is added by ajax after the document has come ready, it doesn't find that class. So, how can i fire it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here since your class have been added dynamically:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("body").on('change','.tmvc_err', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tmvc_err');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on('change', ".tmvc_err", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tmvc_err');
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

If that is added dynamically, you need event delegation -

```
$(document.body).on('change','.tmvc_err', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('tmvc_err');
});
```